# QML ShaderEffectSource does not refresh on childrens visibiliy change

Tags: qt, qml

When using the ShaderEffectSource as preview for another qml element not yet visible, the rendering is not refreshed when the sourceItem's childs are set visible.

In the example press the toggle Button and the text does not appear in the preview until the sourceItem is made visible. On the other hand setting the sourceItems child invisible instantly refreshes the ShaderEffectSource.

Small working example main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Extras 1.4

Item {
    id: main
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 600
    Rectangle {
        id: preview
        width: 533
        height: 400
        // Preview render
        ShaderEffectSource {
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: 25
            sourceItem: liveView
        }
        // Click on preview
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                liveView.visible = true;
                preview.visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: liveView
        visible: false
        anchors.fill: parent
        border.width: 2
        border.color: "black"
        Text {
            id: liveText
            visible: false
            color: "black"
            text: "Live"
            width: parent.width
            font.pointSize: 60
        }
        MouseArea {
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            onClicked: {
                liveView.visible = false;
                preview.visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
    ToggleButton {
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.right: parent.right
        text: "liveText visible"
        onClicked: {liveText.visible = checked;}
    }
}
```

I filed this under https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-66301 but I hope someone can assist me on developing a workaround or tell me if I'm using it completely wrong.

Edit 1: A first workaround is to never make the sourceItem invisible and hide it with a low z behind other objects.